# A problem related to physics, vector, integration

Tags: integration, vectors, physics

This problem is from my Homework. I have the idea of the solution. But I don't know if it is right or not.
I am quoting it from the question.
"Find the work done in moving a particle once around 3/4 th a circle C in the xy plane, If
the circle has center at the origin and radius 3 and the force field is given by,
$\vec{F} = (2x-y+z) \mathbf{i} + (x+y-z^2) \mathbf{j} + (3x-4y+4z) \mathbf{k}$

My idea is, if i calculate it for the whole circle (let it be x) and then do this thing

$a=x-\frac{3}{4}x$
then the value of a which I am getting is it the correct answer? Or, I am wrong?

Comment: What do you mean $x - \frac{3x}{4}$? You are supposed to find for $3/4th$ of the circle. In any case, you need to set up the integral.

Comment: I mean, suppose I find that for the whole. lets all it x. If I subtract 3/4 * x portion from the whole (i.e, answer = x - 3/4 *x), then am I not getting the answer?

Comment: you mean $x - x/4$? But why? Just do till $3 \pi/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is best to just solve this directly. Observe that the circle may be parametrized by

$$\mathbf{r}(\theta)=\cos(\theta) \mathbf{i} + \sin(\theta) \mathbf{j}, \quad \theta \in [0, \tfrac{3\pi}{2}]$$

and that the work is given by

$$\int_{C} \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{r} = \int_{0}^{3\pi/2} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(\theta)) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(\theta) \, d\theta.$$

When you do the dot product, you will get a trigonometric integral. I trust you to take it from there.